# Using a regex to identify EQUIPMENTID numbers - VBA

Tags: regex, vba

Struggling trying to construct a Regexp to identify equipment numbers, I require this to identify equipment numbers in multiple formats including pooled equipment numbers e.g  `AFD21101` or `AFD21101-02-03` or `AFD21101-2-3` including various prefixes as per testdata.

Any tips or feedback welcome, possibly it may be easier with multiple RegExp for each scenario but I had hopped to have a master that would identify any of these patterns and be able to extract from a string for further process in a more detailed order.  Possibly converting to Long format etc.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Hopefully I can return the favour.

What I've tried so far:

```
^[abcpfsmschafddfcpdcdplldt][glvmdugmrxftiichlewsnuabn][mmrprbdpucdsxtvuwcrslbubk][0-9][0-9xX][0-9xX][0-9xX][0-9xX]|[0-9xX-][0-9]|[0-9]

^[abcpfsmschafddfcpdcdplldt][glvmdugmrxftiichlewsnuabn][mmrprbdpucdsxtvuwcrslbubk][0-9][0-9xX][0-9xX][0-9xX][0-9xX]

^(BLM)|(SUB)|

(CVR)|FDR|SMP|CRU|HXC|ATS|AFD|FTS|DIX|DIT|FIT|FCV|KV|FV|CHU|PLW|BCR|DEC|CTR|CWR|V|DSS|PNL|MTR|LUB|LAU|CCL|DBB|TNK|THK|PIT|[0-9][0-9xX][0-9xX][0-9xX][0-9xX]
```

**Testdata** - will have to handle multiple separated by comma or multiline as per testdata examples below

```
// Example test data 1: (CSV+)
CRN21003 (CB-3), CRN21004 (CB-4)

// Example test data 2: (CSV)
CVR21404, CHU21437, AFD21401

// Example test data 3: (Multi-line)
MGD22401 - 16
DEC22401 - 16

// Example test data 4: (In string)
AFD11122 SOME OTHER RANDOM DATA WDC11121_22 SOME OTHER RANDOM DATA 

//Additional matches
AFD21101-03
AFD21101_03
AFD21101-02-03
AFD21101_02_03
AFD21101-2-3
AFD21101_2_3
FDR21407-08
BLM21401
SUB21601
CVR21601
Fdr21601
SMP21501
CRU21501
HXC21501
AFD21501
FTS21X01
DIX21301
DIT22501
FIT21X0X
FCV21501
```

Pattern:

1. Base is max 8 digits

   1. 1-3 letters (A-Z)
   2. 5 Digits (0-9) including X as wildcard
2. Followed by pooled EQUIPMENT ID's

   ```
    e.g. AFD21101-2-3, AFD21101-02-03 or AFD21101_02_03
   ```

   1. `_` or `-` are delimiters indicating abbreviated subsequent equipment id's or ranges.
   2. `AFD21101-02-03` is equivalent to `AFD21101`, `AFD21102`, `AFD21103` in full form

Possible Prefix's continued

```
KV
CHU
PLW
BCR
DEC
CTR
CWR
V
DSS
PNL
MTR
LUB
LAU
CCL
DBB
TNK
THK
PIT
AGM2XXXX - valid
```

Some Invalid matches would be something like

`AGM211011` or `AGMXXXXX` or `21101` or `2110` or `AGM21101-094-034` or `AGM` (prefix only without a trailing 5 digit number/ X wildcard)

Comment: Could you please provide a expected output with your test data?

Comment: expected output would be the Equipment ID i.e AFD21101 or pooled id AFD21101-02-03 for any of the Prefixes as listed

Comment: So, all the values in TestData should match? What should NOT match then? Please make the question a bit more specific, then we have better chance of helping.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, you need to get the strings which starts with substring provided and contains numbers.

You could try the following regex.

```
^(?:BLM|SUB|CVR|FDR|SMP|CRU|HXC|ATS|AFD|FTS|DIX|DIT|FIT|FCV|KV|FV|CHU|PLW|BCR|DEC|CTR|CWR|V|DSS|PNL|MTR|LUB|LAU|CCL|DBB|TNK|THK|PIT)[0-9_-]+
```

**Details:**

1. `^`: start of string
2. `?:`: non capturing group
3. `(?:BLM|SUB|CVR|FDR|SMP|CRU|HXC|ATS|AFD|FTS|DIX|DIT|FIT|FCV|KV|FV|CHU|PLW|BCR|DEC|CTR|CWR|V|DSS|PNL|MTR|LUB|LAU|CCL|DBB|TNK|THK|PIT)`: list of prefixes.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z7FEug/2)

Comment: might be worth checking if _ is actually to be excluded and if, within the character set you show, there is actually an order expected i.e number before hyphen.

Comment: Thankyou Yes Number or X 'Wildcard must be before hyphen or underscore

Answer (score 0):

It isn't 100% clear what you're intending to do because:

1. The test data you've supplied is comprised wholly of *expected* matches
2. The expected output is unclear. Although this largely relays back to point 1!

However, there are many ways of getting the information you require. They all depend on how your *source* data is organised though...

```
//  Example test data 1:

AFD11122 SOME OTHER RANDOM DATA
WDC11121_22 SOME OTHER RANDOM DATA

//  Example test Data 2:

SOME RANDOM DATA AFD11122 AND SOME MORE RANDOM DATA WDC11121_22 WITH SOME MORE
```

Assuming that the data is at the start of the string AND that you want to capture each string as a whole:

```
// Option 1
/^(.*?)\s/
 ^            : Start of string
  (.*?)       : Non-greedy capture group
       \s     : First space (first because the capture group was non-greedy)

// Option 2
/^([ABCDEFHIKLMNPRSTUVWX][ABCDEFHILMNRSTUVWX]?[BCDKLMPRSTUVWX]?[x\d]{5}[_\-\d]*)/i
 ^                                                                                    : Start of string
  (                                                                                   : Start of capture group
   [ABCDEFHIKLMNPRSTUVWX]                                                             : Capture any letter in character set
                         [ABCDEFHILMNRSTUVWX]?                                        : OPTIONALLY [?] capture any letter in character set
                                              [BCDKLMPRSTUVWX]?                       : OPTIONALLY [?] capture any letter in character set
                                                               [x\d]{5}               : Capture any number or x 5 times
                                                                       [_\-\d]*       : Capture any number, hyphen, or underscore until you reach a character not in the set
                                                                               )      : End of capture group
                                                                                 i    : FLAG - case insensitive

// Option 3
/^((?:AFD|BCR|BLM....TNK|V)[\d_\-]*)/i
 ^                                         : Start of string
  (                                        : Start of capture group
   (?:                                     : Start of non-capturing group
      AFD|BCR|BLM....TNK|V                 : List of prefixes separated with "|"
                          )                : End of non-capturing group
                           [\d_\-]*        : Capture any number, hyphen, or underscore until you reach a character not in the set
                                   )       : End of capture group
                                      i    : FLAG - case insensitive

// Option 4
/^([a-z]{1,3}[x\d]{5}[_\-\d]*)/i    :
 ^                                  : Start of string
  (                                 : Start of capture group
   [a-z]{1,3}                       : Capture any letter [range: a-z] 1 to 3 times {1,3}
             [x\d]{5}               : Capture any number [\d] or x [x] 5 times {5}
                     [_\-\d]*       : Capture any number, hyphen, or underscore until you reach a character not in the set
                             )      : End of capture group
                               i    : FLAG - case insensitive
```

Based on your updates to the main question I would stick with `option 4` unless you specifically need to make sure that only the set prefixes are matched.

In the event that your data looks more like `Example Data 2` then the above expressions will need to be altered accordingly; some examples below:

```
/([a-z]{1,3}[x\d]{5}[_\-\d]*)/i        : Remove the ^
/\b([a-z]{1,3}[x\d]{5}[_\-\d]*)/i      : Add a word boundary to the start of the expression
/[^a-z]([a-z]{1,3}[x\d]{5}[_\-\d]*)/i  : Start the expression with anything BUT a letter
```

How you alter it will depend on the data that you're searching through.

**Updated RegEx** based on latest question edits

```
/([a-z]{1,3}(?!xxxxx)[x\d]{5}(?!\d)[_\-\d]*)/ig
```

Comment: Awesome explanation steven,  I have run your examples through the match and it looks like it doesn't match cases where I have multiple equipment ID's separated by commas or over multiple lines.  I have updated the testdata with some more examples.  Hopefully this helps give you more of an idea of what I am battling to acheive

Comment: Hmm, could you add what matches you're expecting to get from the test data? If I use the regex `([a-z]{1,3}[x\d]{5}[_\-\d]*)` I should get all of the matches I'm expecting. If you're only getting one (i.e. the first one) then perhaps you need the `g : global` flag as well as `i : case insensitive`

Comment: I see you're suing **VBA** - to get VBA to return more than the first match you must set the `Global` option to `True` i.e. `regexObject.Global = True`. Similarly the `i : case insensitive` flag is activated by `regexObject.IgnoreCase = True` ((where `regexObject` is the variable name of your `New RegExp()`

Comment: You'll also have to let me know why `AGM21101-094-034` isn't a match and whether the first part `AGM21101` should still be matched?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[A-Z]{1,3}[\dX]{5}([_-])0?\d(\10?\d)?
```

This requires the separator to be the consistent, ie either both `-` or both `_`, by capturing the separator and using a back reference to it `\1`, although the second “pooled ID” is optional.

As far as I can tell, this matches all of your examples.